# Weird behaviour in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am running some test in my controller spec and I found a weird behaviour I cannot explain why this is happen.

My Spec look like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe BooksController do
  let(:user_with_books) { create :user, :with_books }

  ...

  describe 'GET /books/:book_id/owners' do
    it 'shows all owners of the book' do
      book = user_with_books.books.first
      user_2 = create :user
      book.owners << user_2
      get :owners, book_id: user_with_books.books.first.id
      expect(assigns(:users).count).to eq 2
      expect(assigns(:users).first).to eq user_with_books
      expect(assigns(:users).second).to eq user_2
    end
  end
end
```

If I run the command
`rspec spec/controllers/books_controller_spec.rb:31` everything is green:
[image]

But if I run just `rspec`, the test will fail!

[image]

What is Rspec doing on this spec to change the behaviour? What can I do to fix this issue?

**EDIT: My spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you have `DatabaseCleaner` that cleans up the db between tests execution. Please share your `RSpec.config` (should be in `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: I added it now to my question

Comment: And how do you execute `DatabaseCleaner.clean`? In `before(:each)`?

Comment: Nothing set. This snippet of rails_helper is all included with DatabaseCleaner.

Comment: And this was the issue, thanks it worked :)

Comment: Do you want write the solution for it, so that I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `spec_helper.rb`, you are never calling `DatabaseCleaner.clean`. It [should be called](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to *actually* clean the database up in, e. g. `before(:each)` filter:

```
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```